# Virtual environment error: "The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ..."

Tags: python, python-venv

I have successfully created a virtual environment (using `venv`), but I get an error when trying to activate it.

```
PS C:\Users\...> python -m venv projects
PS C:\Users\...> source venv/bin/activate
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ source venv/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image: terminal output]

Why do I get this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your question is? `source` isn't a PowerShell thing, you should be following the instructions for activating the virtual environment in PowerShell.

Comment: When you wrote `source venv/bin/activate`, how did you decide to write that? Please make sure that you are following a guide that is suitable for your operating system. This command only makes sense on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You have created a virtual environment named `projects` (here: `python -m venv *projects*`), but you're trying to activate an environment named `venv` (here: `source *venv*/bin/activate`).
2. `source` is not a powershell command - you cannot use it. Instead, use the powershell script that `venv` provides: `.\projects\Scripts\activate`